# Insert into two tables, one has auto-incremented primary key which is a foreign key of the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to insert into two tables. The first is my product table where the primary key is generated by auto-increment and I then want to insert that primary key into my `product_ingredients` table as a foreign key. How do I go about doing this?

Also to explain a bit more i'm currently trying to implement it so it only submits the rows that are selected in a datagridview using checkboxes

edit: What i've done so far:

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Addproduct
@product_name            VARCHAR(50),
@product_category            VARCHAR(50),
@product_description            VARCHAR(MAX),
@price            money,
@product_stock            VARCHAR(50),
@new_identity    INT    OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO product (product_name,product_category,product_description,price,product_stock)
VALUES (@product_name,@product_category,@product_description,@price,@product_stock)

SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @new_identity AS id

RETURN
END
GO
```

vb.net:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim emptyTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                             Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text) 'Ensures all fields are filled'
        If Not emptyTextBoxes.Any() Then
            Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("Addproduct", connection)
            CMD.Parameters("@Product_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).value = tbName.Text
            CMD.Parameters("@product_category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = tbCategory.Text
            CMD.Parameters("@product_description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = tbDescription.Text
            CMD.Parameters("@price", SqlDbType.Money).Direction = tbPrice.Text
            CMD.Parameters("@pproduct_stock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = tbStock.Text

            CMD.Parameters("@New_Identity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim NewID = CMD.Parameters("@New_Identity").Value



        Else
            MsgBox("All fields must be filled")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Good luck with Sql Injection. However if you need to know which value has been assigned to the record added to the table Product, search for SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: That code doesnt even try to do any insert, let alone 1:m with RI

Comment: @plutonix Well it it inserts the sql string but i don't know how to do the other part that's the point lol

Comment: @steve thanks that sounds useful i'll look it up

Comment: I would recommend stored procedure and make sure your second table has a foreign key to the other table that points to the primary key... 

Comment: @Zaggler that's what i'm currently trying, however i'm a bit confused how to call the stored procedure in vb.net (i've not used them before)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.  Have your insert routine return SCOPE_IDENTITY().

You should look at parameterizing your query.  It will make your code less vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should also look at the SqlHelper class

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/555870/SQL-Helper-Class-Microsoft-NET-Utility

It's not entirely clear what data access methods you are using.  I guess that's part of your question

I like to plain old ADO.NET with the SqlHelper class.

```
' Add record to database   
    Dim id as Integer =  SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connection, "usp_product_ins", product_name, product_category, product_description)
```

Here's an example insert procedure:

```
enter code here
-- Insert stored prodedure.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_product_ins] 
    @product_name varchar(32),
    @product_category int,
    @product_description varchar(255) 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @result int = -1;

    INSERT INTO product (Product_Name, Product_Category, product_description)
    Values (@product_name, @product_category, @product_description)

    If (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) SET @result = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    Select @result as Id;


END
```

You don't have to use a stored procedure or the SqlHelper class.
You can just use inline sql (with parameters) and wrap your values up
as SqlParameters (System.Data.SqlClient namespace) and call ExecuteScalar
directly

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with StoredProcedure. Create SP following code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProcedureName
@product_name            VARCHAR(20),
@parameters2            VARCHAR(20), --define all parameters like this
@new_identity    INT    OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO My_Table (product_name,TableCoumn2)
VALUES (@product_name,@parameter2)

SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @new_identity AS id

RETURN
END
```

**Calling Stored Procedure from VB.Net**

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim emptyTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                         Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text) 'Ensures all fields are filled'
If Not emptyTextBoxes.Any() Then
   Dim CMD as new sqlCommand("InsertProcedureName",YourConnectionObject)       
   CMD.parameters("@product_name", sqlDBType.Int).value = tbName.Text
'repeat above line code for all the parameters defined in stored procedure
       CMD.parameters("@New_Identity",sqlDBType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
   'Similarly for all parameters declared in stored procedure
   CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
   Dim NewID = CMD.Parameters("@New_Identity").Value

   'Use this NewID as foriegn key

Else
    MsgBox("All fields must be filled")
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps and gives you an idea. Thanks

Comment: Just a side note, it's important to dispose objects once you are done with them. On another note you don't pass a connection instance to your command therefore none of it will work...

Comment: @Zaggler, edited my answer. He can use Using statement that will handle dispose of objects auto. Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i hope you're still around but i'm trying to implement the code but currently the parameters in my vb.net are saying overload resolution failed because no accessible 'item' accepts this number of arguments? Also says param_1_value is undeclared... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to define all parameters in stored procedure, then same parameters names in code. parameters values would be your textboxes values. makes sense ?

Comment: Yeah it does make sense hold on i'm going to update my question to show what i have so far, i'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Sorry to rush you but it's due today so any ideas?